# Hibernate not reading latest data

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to build a ecommerce application with the following architecture
1.  Database server Mysql - for storing products, customer info ,order etc.
2.  Webserver (Glassfish 4.1.1) - To Provide data  to client/Android App, it fetches data from database using hibernate 4.3
3.  Standalone java  client developed using swings - To add product, customer info and processing order, it pushes data to database using raw sql command using jdbc

[image]

Webserver is able to read data using hibernate but if client do any insert/update through backend , webserver is not showing that updated data until if re intialize the session factory

is there anyway to do it without re-init

below is my code for int and hibernate.cfg

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure();
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
configuration.getProperties()).build();            
sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Hibernate.cfg

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ order_management?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">abc123</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate uses several types of caches and does not read directly from the database all the time. You can read more about this [here](https://www.journaldev.com/2969/hibernate-caching-first-level-cache).

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate cache is a local cache in your web-server. Data is cached in local as and when your web application reads them.

In your case you require a distributed cache like redis in which both your web-application and java client can share the data